# Trying to use Pydumpck but getting error. What is the required version of PyInstaller for Pydumpck?

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm trying to use pydumpck to convert `.exe` to `.py` following this video: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPgI3R1zpo0`
However I encounter the following error:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer import get_archive, get_data, get_content, get_archive_content
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_archive' from 'PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer' (C:\Users\jjk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\cliutils\archive_viewer.py)
```

I'm thinking its because I installed wrong version of `PyInstaller` but I don't know where can I find the correct version. I'm wondering if anyone have encountered similar problem. Any help will be appreciated!